# Create own menu_button in ALV toolbar

Tags: toolbar, abap, alv

I have to create a menu_button in my ALV toolbar,

I searched in SCN and I found some examples.

I know that we have to create a button with the btn_type = 2

like that :

```
  CLEAR: ls_buttn.
  ls_buttn-icon                   = gi_livra.
  ls_buttn-butn_type              = 2.
  ls_buttn-text                   = 'Vue Livraison'.
  ls_buttn-quickinfo              = 'Vue Livraison'.
  ls_buttn-function               = 'LIVRAISON'.
  APPEND ls_buttn TO e_object->mt_toolbar.
```

After that I have to handle menu button im my class
like that:

```
METHODS handle_menubtn FOR EVENT menu_button OF cl_gui_alv_grid
                  IMPORTING e_object e_ucomm,
```

After that to implement it

```
METHOD handle_menubtn.
    IF e_ucomm = 'LIVRAISON'.
      CALL METHOD e_object->add_function
        EXPORTING
          fcode = 'DISPLAY'
          text  = 'DISPLAY'.
    ENDIF.
  ENDMETHOD.
```

But it does not work. The debugger does not go into this method when I click on my button.

Why?

Comment: It might be a missing handler registration or something else - it's hard to tell without a complete minimal working example.

Comment: Thanks you have right. Can i put icon in this menu list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you did is right but maybe you forgot to

```
SET HANDLER lr_event->handle_menubtn FOR your_alv.
```

Regards,

Comment: You have right Thanks, But can i put Icon on the menu